# Convert String to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: decimal, currency

I use the code below to add two number strings from divs and display the result in another div. It functions as intended, however, when 2.50 & 2.00 are added from the strings the result is displayed as 4.5. How can I format the result to show 2 decimal places?

I have fiddled with toFixed() without success.
The html:

```
</div>
        <div class="C selectt form-group mb-4"> 
          <select id="clientOrder" type="pickup" name="message" class="form-control" required>
            <option disabled selected value>Please select an item</option>
            <option data-price="3.00">Item 1</option></option>
            <option data-price="6.00">Item 2</option></option>
            <option data-price="5.00">Item 3</option></option>
            <option data-price="9.00">Item 4</option></option></select>
          </div>
<!-- **** Sides Table ****  -->
<div class="sidesContainer form-group mb-4 w-100" id="sidesContainer">
        <table class="sides">
          <caption>Add Your Sides</caption>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="side1" data-price="2.50" class="item"><label for="side1">Side 1</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="side2" data-price="2.50" class="item"><label for="side2">Side 2</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="side3" data-price="2.50" class="item"><label for="side3">Side 3</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="side4" data-price="2.50" class="item"><label for="side4">Side 4</label></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="side5" data-price="2.50" class="item"><label for="side5">Side 5</label></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="" id="side6" data-price="2.50" class="item"><label for="side6">Side 6</label></td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
<!-- **** Order Total **** -->
<div class="sidesContainer form-group mb-4 w-100" hidden>Your total is $<span id="sum0" class="item"></span></div>
<div class="sidesContainer form-group mb-4 w-100" hidden>Your total is $<span id="sum1" class="item"></span></div>
<div class="sidesContainer form-group mb-4 w-100">Your total is $<span id="sum"></span></div>
```

The functions:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// **** Sides Values ****
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidesContainer').on('change', function() {
    update_total();
        $('#sum').text(parseFloat($('#sum0').text()) +  parseFloat($('#sum1').text()));
  });

  function update_total() {
    var tot = 0;
    var price = 0;
    $('#sidesContainer input:checked').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      if (price > 0) {      
        tot += +price;
      }
    });
    $('#sidesContainer select').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($("option:selected", this).data('price')).toFixed(2);
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += price;
      }
    });
    $('#sum0').html(tot.toFixed(2));
  }
  update_total();
});

// **** Items Values ****

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clientOrder').on('change', function() {
    update_sum();
        $('#sum').text(parseFloat($('#sum0').text()) +  parseFloat($('#sum1').text()));
  });

  function update_sum() {
    var tot = 0;
    var price = 0;
    $('#clientOrder option:selected').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      if (price > 0) {      
        tot += +price;
      }
    });
    $('#clientOrder select').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($("option:selected", this).data('price')).toFixed(2);
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += price;
      }
    });
    $('#sum1').html(tot.toFixed(2));
  }
  update_sum();
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you include the full code so we can make a fiddle?

Comment: I updated the original question with the html and the script.

Answer (score 0):

Plz try

```
.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

This converts the number to a local number with minimum of 2 and maximum of 2 digits.
`en-us` gives you a dot as separator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: I do not know how to implement that. The string changes with user input, so the value is not constant.

Comment: Instead of using .tofixed(2) you use my function above.

Comment: I do not know where in the script to put that.

Comment: On the places where u have `.tofixed(2) `. Replace that with my code